# vim: Editing po and mo files on windows

Tags: vim, gettext, po, mo

I'm using gvim on Windows and I'm trying to configure it for easy editing of po files- mainly I just want to generate an mo file in the same directory whenever I save.

Looking at [po.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=695) it *appears* I can do this, but I'm not clear on how to setup this up.

I downloaded gettext for windows and looking at the po.vim page it looks like I can set its location with these variables:

```
Information about the translator and language team is supplied by two 
  global variables: 'g:po_translator' and 'g:po_lang_team'. They should 
  be defined in the ".vimrc" (UNIX) or "_vimrc" (Windows) file. If they 
  are not defined, the default values (descriptive strings) are put 
  instead.
```

Now I have this in my _vimrc (the location of where I saved gettext):

```
let g:po_translator='C:\G_Drive\code\gettext\bin\msgfmt.exe'
```

When I save po files it still does not generate an mo file. Am I misunderstanding how this plugin works? How can hook up po.vim to msgfmt.exe to generate mo files when I save- if this is even possible? Also I'd rather not put msgfmt.exe in path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `msgfmt` commands in [po.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=695) are hardcoded to the shell command `msgfmt`, which will therefore only work on Unix systems, not Windows.

Furthermore, the `g:po_translator` global variable is only used to set defaults for the `TranslatorInfo` which inserts your name and the name of the translation team in the header of your `.po` file. In other words, in this context "translator" means "the person who last translated the file."

Comment: Note regarding Unix systems: if you are using mingw32/cygwin, it might work for you (not tested).